# format InputNumber without rounding bound value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm running an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Blazor Server project, and I have a form that has an `InputNumber` that is binding to a `decimal` type.

I have a method that does metric to imperial unit conversion on this field, and I am **not** doing `Math.Round` or `Math.Ceiling` in the conversion method because repeated toggling back and forth would cause the value to shift significantly.

What I want to do is introduce a mask on the `InputNumber` to have it **display** a rounded value, but not actually round the `@bind-Value`. I saw that there is an option to include `@bind-Value:format="@formatSpecifier"` but it hasn't worked for me - I have tried to set `@formatSpecifier` to `"D"`, `"F"`, `"N"`, etc. but it hasn't worked. I also would want to supply a custom format like `.ToString ("#.##")` or something along those lines. How can I do this?

Code below:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Dimensions.Count; i++)
{
    <InputNumber class="form-control" @bind-Value="Model.Dimensions[i].Height"></InputNumber>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present, it seems that asp.net core Blazor Input component doesn't support for binding decimal, double, float data type with configurable formatting, check [this thread](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5523). So, if you want to format the data, I suggest you could format it before binding the value or try to use JavaScript to format the value.

Comment: that's a shame - thanks. i'll leave this open in case anyone contributes a hacky fix. if i forget to accept your answer in a few days, let me know and i'll do it.